# Can't get the hover working

Tags: html, css

My number 3 is rotating on Y 360 degrees.
When I hover my number 3, it's stops turning.
I tried on the class named "drie"`:hover display;none;` but that won't work.
Even on the webkit form.

I can't find out what the problem is..
I have made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chronel/mmKPn/) for you guys.

If you guys still can't find the problem, here is my website to sorta test it aswell if needed. It's a report for school btw :) [School Report](http://rdv-design.com/stageverslag2/home.html)

Hover over the Tie and scroll down, here is where you will see the number 3.

My website only uses css and css3.

Someone has a suggestion that would help? Thanks!

~~~***UPDATE***~~~

As I checked my jsFiddle good, I only changed the display that works.
The only problem excist on my website by codes above I suggest..

```
#shirt img{
    position:absolute;
    left:auto;
    right:auto;
    margin-left:-266px;
}

#shirt_line img{
    position:absolute;
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    margin-top:-130px;
    margin-left:-4px;
    left: auto;
    right:auto;
}

.pochet{
    position:absolute;
    right:118px;
    top:465px;
    width:247px;
    height:287px;
    z-index:1;
    transition:.85s;
}

.pochet:hover{
    top: 230px; 
}

#borstzakje{
    position:absolute;
    right:120px;
    top:480px;
    width:247px;
    height:287px;
    z-index:2;
}

.stropdashouder img{
    position:absolute;
    width:116px;
    height:274px;
    top:0px;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-left:-60px;
    cursor:pointer;
    z-index:1;
}




.vierkant > div{
    position:absolute;
    background-color:;
    height:254px;
    width:116px;
    top:0;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-58px;
    z-index:10;

    -webkit-transition-duration: 1.2s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1.2s;
    -o-transition-duration: 1.2s;
    transition-duration: 1.2s;
}

.vierkant > div:hover{
    margin-left:0;
    background-color:#FF6600;
    height:90%;
    width:90%;
    top:5%;
    left:5%;
    z-index:10;
}

.vierkant div.content{
    opacity:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    top:0%;
    left:0%;
    overflow:scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}

.vierkant:hover div.content{
    opacity:1;

    -webkit-transition-duration: 0s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0s;
    transition-duration: 0s;
}

#contenttekst{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;    
    margin-left:-68px;
    top:5%;
    left:10%;
    text-align:left;
}

#start{
    position:relative;
    width:750px;;
    height:100%;
    margin-left:-48px;
    left:-0%;
    text-align:left;
    z-index:1;
}


#tekst{
    position:absolute;
    width:80%;
    height:95%;
    top:2%;
    left:auto;
    right:auto;
    display: none;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    z-index:4;

}

#stropdas{  
    position:absolute;
    width:116px;
    height:274px;
    top:0px;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

#ikzelf{
    position:absolute;
    float:right;
    padding: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
    top:50px;
    left:590px;
    z-index:1;
}

#leerdoel2{
    margin-left:-26px;
}


/* vlekken */

#blok{
    position:absolute;
    width:576; 
    height:104;
    top:1950px;
    left:68px;
    z-index:1;
    opacity:0.1;
}




/*html, css, js*/
#vlek1{
    background-image:url(../img/vlek1.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    position:absolute;
    top:1800px;
    left:20px;
    width:163px;
    height:113px;

    -webkit-transition-duration: 1.2s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1.2s;
    -o-transition-duration: 1.2s;
    transition-duration: 1.2s;
}

#vlek1:hover{
    position:absolute;
    left:20px;
    width:;
    height:;
}

#vlek1 #html{
    position:absolute;
    top:150px;
    left:60px;
    width:163px;
    height:113px;
    opacity:0;

    -webkit-transition-duration: 1.2s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1.2s;
    -o-transition-duration: 1.2s;
    transition-duration: 1.2s;
}

#vlek1:hover #html{
    position:absolute;
    top:150px;
    left:60px;
    width:163px;
    height:113px;

    opacity:1;
    z-index:2;

    /*-webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    transition-duration: 0.8s;*/
}

#vlek1:hover #html:hover img{
    display:none;
    visibility:hidden;
}

#vlek3{
    background-image:url(../img/vlek3.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    position:absolute;
    top:1800px;
    left:310px;
    width:163px;
    height:113px;

    -webkit-transition-duration: 1.2s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1.2s;
    -o-transition-duration: 1.2s;
    transition-duration: 1.2s;
}

#vlek3:hover{
    position:absolute;
    left:310px;
    width:;
    height:;
}

#vlek3 #css{
    position:absolute;
    top:150px;
    left:-230px;
    width:163px;
    height:113px;
    opacity:0;

    -webkit-transition-duration: 1.2s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1.2s;
    -o-transition-duration: 1.2s;
    transition-duration: 1.2s;
}

#vlek3:hover #css{
    position:absolute;
    top:150px;
    left:-230px;
    width:163px;
    height:113px;

    opacity:1;
    z-index:2;

    /*-webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    transition-duration: 0.8s;*/
}

#vlek3:hover #css:hover img{
    display:none;
    visibility:hidden;
}

#vlek4{
    background-image:url(../img/vlek4.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    position:absolute;
    top:1800px;
    left:600px;
    width:163px;
    height:113px;

    -webkit-transition-duration: 1.2s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1.2s;
    -o-transition-duration: 1.2s;
    transition-duration: 1.2s;
}

#vlek4:hover{
    position:absolute;
    left:600px;
    width:;
    height:;
}

#vlek4 #jsandjq{
    position:absolute;
    top:150px;
    left:-520px;
    width:163px;
    height:113px;
    opacity:0;

    -webkit-transition-duration: 1.2s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1.2s;
    -o-transition-duration: 1.2s;
    transition-duration: 1.2s;
}

#vlek4:hover #jsandjq{
    position:absolute;
    top:150px;
    left:-520px;
    width:163px;
    height:113px;

    opacity:1;
    z-index:2;

    /*-webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    transition-duration: 0.8s;*/
}

#vlek4:hover #jsandjq:hover img{
    display:none;
    visibility:hidden;
}

/*eind html, css, js*/

#vlek2{
    position:absolute;
    float:right;
    padding: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
    top:30px;
    left:490px;
    z-index:0;
}


/*eind vlekken*/

/*#knoopvlak{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%; 
    height:114px;
    top:400px;
    margin:0 auto;
}*/


/* Turning Knopen */
.knoop1 img{
    position:absolute;
    width:114px;
    height:114px;
    top:400px;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-left:-195px;
    z-index:0;

    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    transition-duration: 0.8s;

    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
    transition-property: transform;

    overflow:hidden;
}

.knoop1:hover img{
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(360deg); 
    -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
}

.knoop2 img{
    position:absolute;
    cursor:pointer;
    width:114px;
    height:114px;
    top:700px;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-left:-195px;
    z-index:0;

        -webkit-transition-duration: 1.6s;
        -moz-transition-duration: 1.6s;
        -o-transition-duration: 1.6s;
        transition-duration: 1.6s;

    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
    transition-property: transform;

    overflow:hidden;
}

.knoop2:active img{
    -webkit-transform:rotate(1126deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(1126deg); 
    -o-transform:rotate(1126deg);
}

#één img{
    position:absolute;
    width:24px;
    height:86px;
    margin-top:-96px;
    left:440px;

    -webkit-transition-duration: 1.6s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1.6s;
    -o-transition-duration: 1.6s;
    transition-duration: 1.6s;

    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
    transition-property: transform;

    overflow:hidden;
}

#één:hover img{
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(360deg); 
    -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
}

/* TWEE */
.object {
    position: absolute;

    transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}
.van {
    margin-top:-104px;
    left:440px;
}

#twee:hover .move-right{
    transform: translate(300px,0);
    -webkit-transform: translate(300px,0); /** Chrome & Safari **/
    -o-transform: translate(300px,0); /** Opera **/
    -moz-transform: translate(300px,0); /** Firefox **/
}
/* EIND TWEE */

#drie{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:-104px;
    left:440px;
    width:58px;
    height:101px;
    z-index:1;

    -webkit-animation:rotate 5s linear 0s infinite normal none; /* Safari & Chrome */
    -moz-animation:rotate 5s linear 0s infinite normal none;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
    -moz-backface-visibility: visible;
}



@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    from {
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg); 
      -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
      }
    to {
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
      -moz-transform: rotateY(360deg);
    }
}

#square{
    background-color:#ff6600;
    position:absolute;
    width:58px;
    height:101px;
    margin-top:-104px;
    left:440px;
    z-index:9999;
    opacity:0.1;
}
```

Comment: Post relevant code here please.

Comment: Do you want the `3` to be static until you `:hover`? and then back to static when you stop hovering?

Comment: Btw, if i were you, you should add for -moz- etc too ;)

Comment: @Shadow Wizard then I have to post my full css here, I won't do that. ;) and at andyb when I hover my number 3, I see 1 big square rotation, it has to be the number 3 instead of the big square

Comment: So you demand those who want to help you to visit your site then find relevant code themselves? I won't do that.

Comment: I am sorry, the code is my full css. that's like 600 lines. it's because it's only made of CSS3.

Comment: Why is it not relevant? I don't get it.. sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.vierkant div:hover` rule is also applying since the element `id="drie"` is a `<div>` descendent of the `<div class="vierkant">`

Change the rule to `.vierkant > div:hover` to only target the direct children. This will stop the multiple `3`s appearing.

Now the `3` seems to be spinning constantly, which is not the same as the other numbers, which only animate on `:hover` so it seems that you really just want the following CSS.

```
#drie {
position: absolute;
    left:440px;
}

#drie:hover {
    -webkit-animation:rotate 5s linear 0s infinite normal none; /* Safari & Chrome */
    -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
}
```

If you want `3` to spin constantly, just combine into a single selector:

```
#drie {
position: absolute;
    left:440px;
    -webkit-animation:rotate 5s linear 0s infinite normal none; /* Safari & Chrome */
    -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: That was the awnser I was searching for! Thanks alot and sorry about the loads of codes..

Comment: Glad I could help! Next time, if you can, please try to reproduce the problem in a fiddle and post the relevant code.

Comment: I did though the whole code was relevant, hehe..

Answer (score 2):

If you want that your number should get rotate even after hover than just remove this `display:none;`

```
#drie:hover{
    -webkit-animation:rotate 5s linear 0s infinite normal none; /* Safari & Chrome */
    -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
    /*display:none;*/
}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmKPn/5/)

Comment: Thanks for that, but theres another problem. please see my website for the real problem!

Comment: @RyandeVries It looks that this is also working on your website. May be you have changed it :)

Comment: I will put an background-image in it and you will see the problem. please check it up in Chrome if you did not before! ^^ As I can see you have to hover right over the middle, kinda weird though..